# How to return an array of billing addresses and shipping addresses in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to make Magento return a PHP array of all shipping/billing addresses that the logged in user has used in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in that will do what you want.  You can, however, create such an array by grabbing the address collection.

Something like this

```
    $all = array();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    foreach($customer->getAddressesCollection() as $address)
    {
            $all[] = $address;
            //$all[] = $address->getData();
    }
    var_dump($all);
```

Comment: Could you also use `$all = $customer->getAddressCollection()->toArray()`?

Comment: @clockworkgeek probably. This is 110% personal preference, but I never like recommending casts and cast-like-methods for newbie questions in forums.  It adds oen more thing for the OP to have to figure out.  A dumb brute force loop is easier to understand.